# Append to empty list with multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiple-processes, process-pool

From a broader level, this is what I am trying to do - append to an empty list an item it reads from the elements list with multiprocessing pool, but this is printing an empty list. Any idea where I am going wrong, or any alternative to achieve the same task in parallel?

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocess import Pool

empty = []

elements = np.arange(10)

def fill_list(element):
    empty.append(element)

with Pool(5) as p:
    p.map(fill_list, elements)
    
print(empty)
```

Comment: the list is not shared between processes

Comment: Thought it was easy, no? How else can I go about it, any idea? @Bharel

Comment: Can you clarify, you say "with multiprocessing pool", but you import "from multiprocess import Pool". Is the import a typo for [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or are you using a [third party library](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/)?

Comment: I am using a kernel in jupyter. The multiprocess module is a fork from multiprocessing module, and it has better compatibility with jupyter. Just assume it's multiprocessing. It's not a typo, but if that helps ..